# Magento 2 : Creating JS Mixins for anonymous functions?

Tags: magento2, javascript, mixins

I would like turn all my js overwrites into mixins. I'm trying to create a mixin for the following file:

view/frontend/web/js/action/place-order.js

But the function in there doesn't have a name

'    return function (paymentData, messageContainer) {'

When googling and checking [magento 2 docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html) I can't find anything about how to turn a function without a name into a mixin. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you use extra module for purpose customises on place order js

In module you need define file `requirejs-config.js`

path

```
app\code\YourVendor\ModuleName\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js
```

Content

```
var config = {
     config: {
       mixins: {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order': {
            'YourVendor_ModuleName/js/action/place-order-mixin': true
            }
        }
     }
};
```

file `YourVendor_ModuleName/js/action/place-order-mixin`

```
define([
 'jquery',
 'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
   'use strict';

    return function (placeOrderAction) {

      /** Override default place order action */
       return wrapper.wrap(placeOrderAction, function (originalAction, paymentData, messageContainer) {
          //Your extras logic here
          //Add extended functionality here

          return originalAction(paymentData, messageContainer);
      });
    };
});
```